# Nested loop within JS object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm refactoring some code that I have to try and change out page content on an interval. I'm looping an original JSON object to create a sub array of content pertaining to pages by page ID. Currently, by doing a console.log, I have the correct object and structure.

The issue is, I'm trying to loop the page_ids with my set  interval function, then within that I need to loop the content array in order to populate the html correctly. I think I have the setInterval loop around pages correct but I'm not sure, and I know I don't have the content looped within it properly.

For the below example, it should display "left 93" in the left dev and "right 93" in the right div on page load, and then after the interval would change to pageID 94 and show "Page 94" in the div.

How can I alter this loop structure within the setInterval?

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nr37tL9j/6/

```js
const original_json = [{
  "pageID": "93",
  "page_type_id": "2",
  "display_id": "2",
  "slide_order": null,
  "duration": "74",
  "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
  "panel_id": "86",
  "panel_type_id": "2",
  "cont_id": "138",
  "contID": "138",
  "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
 },
 {
  "pageID": "93",
  "page_type_id": "2",
  "display_id": "2",
  "slide_order": null,
  "duration": "74",
  "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
  "panel_id": "87",
  "panel_type_id": "3",
  "cont_id": "139",
  "contID": "139",
  "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
 },
  {
  "pageID": "94",
  "page_type_id": "2",
  "display_id": "2",
  "slide_order": null,
  "duration": "74",
  "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
  "panel_id": "87",
  "panel_type_id": "3",
  "cont_id": "139",
  "contID": "139",
  "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nPage 94<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
 },
  {
  "pageID": "95",
  "page_type_id": "2",
  "display_id": "2",
  "slide_order": null,
  "duration": "74",
  "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
  "panel_id": "87",
  "panel_type_id": "3",
  "cont_id": "139",
  "contID": "139",
  "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nPage 95<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
 }
]; 

let counter = 0;

    var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
    var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
    var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');
    
    var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
    var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
    var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');


// loop through original json
// for each item, get page ID and see if we've already created a new Page object for it
// if we have, add the object from the original json to the "content" array of the new page object
// otherwise, create a new Page object to put in our new array
const pages_array = original_json.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, original_json){
 const current_pageID = item.pageID; 
  const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID); 
  
  if (exisiting_page === undefined){
   const new_Page = {
     pageID: current_pageID,
      content: [item]
    }
    pages_array.push(new_Page); 
  } else {
   exisiting_page.content.push(item)
  }
  
  return pages_array; 
}, []);

// Open console to see data
console.clear(); 
console.log(pages_array);//this prints correct array

setInterval(()=>{//here I loop through pages, but i need to loop within here over content to render html
    const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter]; 
 if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2){
        
        fullColumn.style.display = "none";

        if(currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 2){

            leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;

        }else if(currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 3){

            rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;
        }

    }

    
    

    counter += 1; 
    if (counter === pages_array.length){
        counter = 0; 
    }
    
        console.log(currentJSONobject.content);


}, 1500)
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">


            <!-- Half Page Divs -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">
                
                <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">        

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn">
                
              <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

        </div>
        <!-- End Row Middle -->
```

UPDATE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the previous solution as the issue was a series of syntax errors.  Working code is in the snippet.

```js
const original_json = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nPage 94<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "95",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nPage 95<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  }
];

let counter = 0;

var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');


// loop through original json
// for each item, get page ID and see if we've already created a new Page object for it
// if we have, add the object from the original json to the "content" array of the new page object
// otherwise, create a new Page object to put in our new array
const pages_array = original_json.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, original_json) {
  const current_pageID = item.pageID;
  const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);

  if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
    const new_Page = {
      pageID: current_pageID,
      content: [item]
    }
    pages_array.push(new_Page);
  } else {
    exisiting_page.content.push(item)
  }

  return pages_array;
}, []);

// Open console to see data
console.clear();
console.log(pages_array); //this prints correct array

setInterval(() => { //here I loop through pages, but i need to loop within here over content to render html
  const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter];
  if (currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2) {

    fullColumn.style.display = "none";

    if (currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 2) {

      leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;

    } else if (currentJSONobject.panel_type_id == 3) {

      rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content;
    }

  }


  console.log(pages_array[counter])

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === pages_array.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 1500)
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">


  <!-- Half Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">

    <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn">

    <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

</div>
<!-- End Row Middle -->
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to quite get it yet, at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nr37tL9j/21/. Assuming too that there may sometimes be 3 or 4 content rows for each page

Comment: I'm trying to dump the content of each in the console, without worrying so much about the HTML and it seems like it's failing at a certain point with the extra counter

Comment: Notice the names are now currentJSONobjectL and currentJSONobjectR.  I'll have a look at your fiddle.

Comment: Ok thank you! I did change out the names but I think after it's h it all 3 elements, it fails on pageID

Comment: @Whisou138 Several issues on fiddle.  No element with id fullContent.   You refer to it as fullColumn instead of fullContent in loop.  You need to break up your if statement so it's not nested.

Comment: I still get undefined property, did you happen to have the new fiddle link?

Comment: Add a div with id    fullContent, then change fullColumn.style to fullContent.style.

Comment: "sometimes be 3 or 4 content rows for each page" is going to be another issue to solve.  I suggest a new question after you have fixed these other issues.

Comment: I just mean I'm trying to make it a dynamic function, which is why I thought I could just loop on the 'content' arrays for each pageID at interval change. See my update above is an image of the error I'm getting in the console after making the div changes you suggested. Are you not getting a console error at all on your fiddlle?

Comment: no console error for me.  I am getting the objects in the console.

Comment: Can you link the working fiddle for me? I can't clear the errors. When I visit the link I gave you it's not working

Comment: forget that.  was on my end.

Comment: No problem, it seemed like it was fine but I wasn't sure

Comment: As long as the fiddle you're using is showing the appropriate things in the console I can tinker with the HTML but it seems like as soon as mine gets through the first three it fails on resetting

Comment: It's totally working on my end.  I put a console.log in the loop.  Run my snippet.

Comment: Thank you, I see now. I'll now work on accessing the content to show in the html